# Plotting multiple lines with updating Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a Pandas Dataframe that is consistently updating, it looks like this:

```
Company   Part   Size  Date
A         1      .01   01/01
A         1      .04   01/02
A         2      .03   02/01
A         2      .07   01/01
```

So this table is updating when new files are introduced to the directory it is monitoring. I would like to plot the "Size" on the y-axis and "Date" on the x-axis, with each line being a "company" and "part". I have tried experimenting with the animate package in matplotlib but I'm not sure how to implement that with an updating dataframe. Thanks!

Comment: You can writing those data into the txt then we can do animate

Comment: The directory gets new txt files that are parsed.

Comment: Or write the images to a folder and animate the last 10?